# Symfony 2 - rearrange form fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

In our Symfony2 project we have a very complex structure for forms with embedded forms.... Now we got the requirement to bring the output of the form in an specific order.

And here is the problem: We use the form_widget(form) and now we are looking for a solution in the object (e.g. via annotations) or the formbuilder to move a specific field to the end of the form. in symfony 1.4 it was the widget-movefield() function, i guess...

Thx...

Answer (score 10):

You can re-order the fields using this bundle: https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryOrderedFormBundle

This allows you to do things like this:

```
$builder
->add('g', 'text', array('position' => 'last'))
->add('a', 'text', array('position' => 'first'))
->add('c', 'text')
->add('f', 'text')
->add('e', 'text', array('position' => array('before' => 'f')))
->add('d', 'text', array('position' => array('after' => 'c')))
->add('b', 'text', array('position' => 'first'));
```

This was going to be in core, but was rejected and pulled out into a bundle.

Answer (score 8):

Had same issue today with the form elements ordering.

Ended up with a trait that will override finishView method and reorder items in children property of a FormView:

```
trait OrderedTrait
{
    abstract function getFieldsOrder();

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        /** @var FormView[] $fields */
        $fields = [];
        foreach ($this->getFieldsOrder() as $field) {
            if ($view->offsetExists($field)) {
                $fields[$field] = $view->offsetGet($field);
                $view->offsetUnset($field);
            }
        }

        $view->children = $fields + $view->children;

        parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);
    }
}
```

Then in type implement getFieldsOrder method:

```
use OrderedTrait;

function getFieldsOrder()
{
    return [
        'first',
        'second',
        'next',
        'etc.',
    ];
}
```

Comment: That is one fine, clean solution! Thanks!

Comment: Its easy to extend this piece of code in order to add weights to the fields list returned by the getFieldsOrder, if someone needs this, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to "reorder" fields. All you need to do is to call `form_label` and/or `form_widget` for each field individually. Assuming you use `Twig` you could, for example, do:

```
<div>{{ form_label(form.firstName) }}</div>
<div>{{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}</div>

<div>{{ form_label(form.lastName) }}</div>
<div>{{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not possible. We have a very complex structure and need the form_widget(form) function, so we have to do this in the backend!

Comment: Have you tried adding fields to the `FormBuilder` instance in desired order?

Comment: Thats not possible. We have round about 80 object-types with dependencys, inheritances and so on, so we CAN'T manipulate such stuff by hand....

Comment: Ok, my colluege did the hack, very dirty, but it works: 

{% set label = form_widget(form.orderlabel) %}
{% set input = form_widget(form.orderinput) %}

{{ form_rest(form) }}

{{ label|raw }}
{{ label|input }}

Would be great, if symfony prevents us for such things in future :D

If somebody knows a clean solution, we are happy about good answers

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution I came up with.

I created a class that my types extend.

```
namespace WF\CORE\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class WfBaseForm extends AbstractType
{

    protected function useFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $fields)
    {
        foreach ($builder->all() as $field) {

            if (!in_array($field->getName(), $fields))
                $builder->remove($field->getName());
        }
    }


    public function reorder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $keys = array())
    {
        $fields         = $builder->all();
        $ordered_fields = array_merge(array_flip($keys), $fields);
        $this->useFields($builder, array());

        foreach($ordered_fields as $field)
            $builder->add($field);

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'base';
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your inherited classes.

```
class AddressType extends WfBaseForm
{ 
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // I add as many fields as I need
        $builder->add( '…');
}
```

This class extends the one above

```
class ModifyAddressType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('title', 'text', array('constraints' => array(new NotBlank())));

        $this->reorder($builder, array('title', 'firstname', 'lastname'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but solved it in a different way. Here is my solution, as an idea for others who are searching for this problem.

You could add all the form fields in an event listener, because here you have all the objects data to decide on the fields order. You could for example use a method from the data object to decide on the fields order:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Don't use $builder->add(), or just for those fields which are always 
    // at the beginning of the form.

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // Now add all the fields in the order you need them to be, e.g by reading
        // the needed order from the data entry. 
        if ($entry->isFieldAFirst()) { 
             $form->add(fieldA);
             $form->add(fieldB);
        } else {
            $form->add(fieldB);
            $form->add(fieldA);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use only form_widget(form) in final template.

Let assume we have two inherited models (ModelA, ModelB) and form types for them (ModelAType, ModelBType)

```
class ModelA {
  private $A;
  private $B;

  // Getters and setters
}

class ModelB extends ModelA {
  private $C;

  // Getters and setters
}

/**
 * @DI\Service(id = "form.type.modelA")
 * @DI\Tag("form.type", attributes={ "alias":"model_a_type" })
 */
class FormAType extends AbstractType {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('A')
      ->add('B')
    ;
  }

   // getName and so on
}

/**
 * @DI\Service(id = "form.type.modelA")
 * @DI\Tag("form.type", attributes={ "alias":"model_b_type" })
 */
class FormAType extends AbstractType {
  public function getParent() {
    return "model_a_type";
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('C')
    ;
  }

   // getName and so on
}
```

If you render formB, you will get A,B,C order, but you want A,C,B.
To accomplish that, create form template and add reference to app. config file:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
   ....
    form:
        resources:
            - YourAppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig


{# src/YourAppBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block model_a_type_widget %}
   {{ form_widget(form.A) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.B) }}
{% endblock model_a_type_widget %}

{% block model_b_type_widget %}
   {{ form_widget(form.A) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.C) }}

   {{ block('model_a_type_widget') }}
{% endblock model_b_type_widget %}
```

Now, when you render formB, you will see desired order and keep code structured.
It happens because every widget rendered only once, so if you render it before calling parent block, you will change their order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right in your controller before you render the template:

```
$form = ...

$view = $form->createView();

// Perform standard array operations to reorder: `$view->children`
// Here's a very simple example:

$firstField = $view->children['firstField'];
unset($view->children['firstField']);
$view->children['firstField'] = $firstField;

return array('form' => $view);
```

`uasort` works as well, however `usort` creates a non-associative array which will break the form rendering later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    <div>{{ form_label(form.title) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.title,{'id': 'blog_title'} )}}</div>

    <div>{{ form_label(form.tag) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.tag,{'id': 'blog_tag'} )}}</div>

    <div>{{ form_label(form.category) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.category,{'id': 'blog_category'} )}}</div>

    <div>{{ form_label(form.image) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.image,{'id': 'blog_image'} )}}</div>

    <div>{{ form_label(form.body) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.body,{'id': 'editor'} )}}</div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```